# How do you decrypt a xml file using BouncyCastle and .pem file?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pem

I have a xml file that has been encrypted and a Pem file that contains a private key and certificate.

```
var bytesToDecrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Encrypted.xml.pem");

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"privateKeyAndCert.pem"))
{
     keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
}

var decrypted = RSADecrypt(bytesToDecrypt, keyPair.Private);
var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
```

1st attempt of decoding throws the exception "input too large for RSA cipher."

```
public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] data, AsymmetricKeyParameter key)
{
    var decryptEngine = new RsaEngine();
    decryptEngine.Init(false, key);
    return decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

2nd attempt completes but the output is random chars and not xml.

```
public static byte[] RSADecryptChunk(byte[] data, AsymmetricKeyParameter key)
{
    try
    {
        var engine = new RsaEngine();
        engine.Init(false, key);

        int blockSize = engine.GetInputBlockSize();

        List<byte> output = new List<byte>();

        for (int chunkPosition = 0; chunkPosition < data.Length; chunkPosition += blockSize)
        {
            int chunkSize = Math.Min(blockSize, data.Length - ((chunkPosition / blockSize) * blockSize));
            output.AddRange(engine.ProcessBlock(data, chunkPosition, chunkSize));
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return null;
    }
}
```

The following command successfully decrypts with openssl so I know the files are correct:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -inform PEM -in "encrypted file path" -out "unencrypted file path" -inkey ".pem file path"
```